# Retract Dataset value without using its Key

Tags: dataset

First of all, I cannot think of a better title for this question.

I have a csv file, [snippet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mu5e-JzQ-A7yUFaE3GiIc5IGluiXhaGO/view?usp=sharing), which is encoded in Japanese. I used the following code to import and it could correctly show the column head, at least, not some random characters.

```
Import["ETC_1.csv","Dataset",CharacterEncoding->"ShiftJIS",HeaderLines->1]
```

I then wanted to do some calculation: col4-col2 (after convert them to `TimeObject`), which I know is the ending and starting time of a travel. However, I do not know how to type in Japanese, which means I cannot type the "column_head" when write a `function` or `query`, e.g. `#head` to do so. I then tried to extract the `Keys` with the following code.

```
dataset[All, (Slot[Normal[dataset[1, Keys]][[1]]] - Slot[Normal[dataset[1, Keys]][[2]]]) &]
```

But it did not work and showed the following error message.

```
Function::slot: Slot[Normal[dataset[1,Keys]][[1]]] (in Slot[Normal[dataset[1,Keys]][[1]]]-Slot[Normal[dataset[1,Keys]][[2]]]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.
```

Could anyone please show me a way to implement this function either by using the `column head` or `column number` and also please show me why I have the above error? Thanks.

Comment: I would convert the Dataset to an Association. Then it is straight forward to either get the keys through the Keys function. Or just continue and extract the values and last use Part and the 3rd and 4th column. 
Doing non trivial computations with Dataset always  confuses me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that slot syntax within a function is restricted to constant values only, literal integers or strings.  This is a restriction of `Function` itself, whether or not it is used to query a `Dataset`:

```
Slot["a"~~"b"] &
```

[image: Function: Slot[a~~b] (in Slot[a~~b]&) should contain a non-negative integer or string.]

In the case at hand, we can evaluate the key expressions and inject them as constants using `With`:

```
With[{k4 = Normal@dataset[1, Keys][[4]], k2 = Normal@dataset[1, Keys][[2]]}
, dataset[All, TimeObject@Slot[k4] - TimeObject@Slot[k2]&]
]
```

[image: dataset with time intervals]

We may want to hoist out the common subexpression (the second version uses an undocumented form of `With`):

```
With[{keys = Normal@dataset[1, Keys]}
, With[{k4 = keys[[4]], k2 = keys[[2]]}
  , dataset[All, TimeObject@Slot[k4] - TimeObject@Slot[k2]&]
  ]
]


With[{keys = Normal@dataset[1,Keys]}, {k4 = keys[[4]], k2 = keys[[2]]}
, dataset[All, TimeObject@Slot[k4] - TimeObject@Slot[k2]&]
]
```

**Simpler Alternative?**

Since the operations are being expressed positionally anyway, we might consider a simpler alternative using `Part` syntax:

```
dataset[All, TimeObject@#[[4]] - TimeObject@#[[2]]&]
```

[image: dataset with time intervals]

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it could be related to the value passed to `Slot` is not evaluated and wrapped it with `Evaluate` before passing to `Slot`. However, it did not work. I did not realize that I can use `With` to do the same thing. Also, I understand the `Slot` syntax better now thanks to your answer. Finally, I really like the undocumented `With` feature you used above and the simpler alternative. Thanks again!